# Validate textarea input for alphanumeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I want to validate textarea which is an Address field, it must contains both of letters and numbers, at least 1 number .
for example : "Laksda Adisucipto street, no 22A."
but when i just type : "Laksda Adisucipto street" (without number) it can show alert "you must enter at least 1 number"

i'm using Twitter Bootstrap and [Validator.js](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)
here's my code

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label for="address" class="control-label"><span>*</span> <?php echo $this->lang->line('address');?></label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="address" rows="5" required name="address" data-error="Address is required"></textarea>
                        <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
                    </div>
```

JS :

```
<script>
$('#address').change(function()  
{  
 var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;  
if(($('#').value.match(letterNumber))   
{  
 return true;  
}  
else  
{   
 alert("message");   
 return false;   
}  
 }  );
```

Comment: What is the question? The code is apparently wrong, since it does not allow any spaces, and it does not even try to check for at least one digit (number).

Comment: The above regex allows even if one doesn't enter a number. A quick and dirty fix - `/^.*[a-zA-Z]+.*[0-9]+.*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#address').blur(function()  
{  
 var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;  
    if(this.value.match(letterNumber))   
      {  
       return true;  
      }  
    else  
    {   
     alert("message");   
     return false;   
    }  
 });
```

you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/oa6eewck/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#address').blur(function()  
{  
 var letterNumber = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;  
    if(this.value.match(letterNumber))   
      {  
       return true;  
      }  
    else  
    {   
     alert("message");   
     return false;   
    }  
 });
```

This function will allow only characters and numbers,it will be good for a input text field but since you are having text area "spaces" and "commas" and "periods" are expected right.

So better follow the expression follows :

```
    $('#address').blur(function()  
        {  
        var hasNumber    = this.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s .,]+$/);
        if ( hasNumber) {
         return true;
        } else {
         alert("message");   
         return false; 
        }
        });
```

Comment: You can add special characters in the reg exp for making this more efficient or if you need to allow more special characters like this.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s .,?"-]+$/);
Hyphen should be atlast or else it will be taken as a character for defining start and end points

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#address').on('change', function () {
    var hasNumber = this.value.match(/\d/);
    var isAlfa    = this.value.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/);

    if ( hasNumber && isAlfa ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("message");   
        return false; 
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvg5obzx/1/)

Answer (score -1):

adeneo's solution is right. but I think isAlfa should have following value

var isAlfa    = this.value.match(/^[A-Za-z\d(-.,) ]+/);